# what is displayFileData in cordova?

Tags: cordova

i really don't like cordova documentation, for simple examples it over complicate things...

[here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#read-a-file-)
inside the function readFile,
i have this function called "displayFileData", but i can't find reference of what is it anywhere... does anibody know?

i'm looking for this because is a dependency function based on this function: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#create-directories

possible that cordova haven't simple set of function separated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that we were supposed to write something like this :)

```
function displayFileData(data){
alert(data);
}
```